# Rank of Logistic Regression Model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, rank

I've built a logistic regression model in R using below lines of code. I tried extracting an element of model object called rank. How is this rank calculated internally?

```
fit = glm(vs ~ hp + mpg, mtcars, family = "binomial")
fit$rank # returns 3
```

Is it simply 1 more than number of independent variables?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the online doc?

Comment: @Limey, "the numeric rank of the fitted linear model" might not be very clear to a non-expert ...

Answer (score 1):

The actual internal calculation is buried deep inside the R machinery: you can trace it down to the [dqrls](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/appl/dqrls.f) Fortran function, where it appears as

> k (integer): k contains the number of columns used in the solution.

(formatting edited slightly); you could go deeper but I don't think it would be helpful.

In general the rank is the number of the columns in the *model matrix*, which in your case includes the intercept, but it may be less if the model matrix is multicollinear. If all of the predictor variables are numeric and non-collinear, and the model includes an intercept (there is no `+0` or `-1` term in the formula), then the rank is indeed one more than the number of predictor variables. If the model includes categorical variables (factors) with >2 levels, or the intercept is omitted, or there are computed terms such as splines or orthogonal polynomials in the model, or interactions, then it gets more complicated.

If you want to do the computation yourself, a very good substitute would be

```r
m <- model.matrix(~ hp + mpg, mtcars)  ## build model matrix (includes intercept)
Matrix::rankMatrix(m)
```

It's conceivable that there are edge cases where the internal machinery of `glm` → `glm.fit` → `C_dqrls` (internal C function) → `dqrls.f` → ... would compute the rank of the model matrix differently from `Matrix::rankMatrix`.